# Going to Bilbao for Christmas and returning to England. Will I have trouble getting back in to complete the 180 days?

Tags: england, return

I've been in England since late October this year, and will be leaving early April, but I plan to travel to Bilbao at Christmas for 5 days, and then return to England where I have been visiting friends. Am I likely to have any trouble getting back in, or with staying for the time I have remaining on my passport? Any insights into the likelihood that there will/won't be a problem?

Comment: What nationality passport do you hold? What has been the purpose of your stay thus far in the UK?

Comment: What ‘180 days’ are you referring to? Once you exit the UK, the admission you were granted on arrival is over. If you want to return, you’ll be seeking a fresh admission.